How do you set 'no-new-privileges' in 'security options' in a Docker Compose file?
I'm running a Checkmarx scan, which raised an error that the Security Opt flag isn't set in the 'docker-compose.yaml' file. I've searched but there seems to be very little on actually setting these options in a docker compose file.
Initially I added the security_opt flag with the 'apparmor=docker-default', which I got from https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/. This got rid of that error but it then raised a new one that the 'no-new-privileges' wasn't set. I've tried various things, but the scanner keeps picking it up. What I've tried so far:
  version: "3.6"
  services:
    myService:
      image: <some image>
      security_opt:
        - apparmor=docker-default
        - no-new-privileges=true

Also tried:
  security_opt: [apparmor=docker-default, no-new-privileges=true] //Apparently security_opt is an array.

This way complains that security_opt is an array and doesn't compile
security_opt:
    apparmor: docker-default
    no-new-privileges: true


YAML syntax note: your first two options are identical; in both cases security_opt is an array of k=v strings. They will deserialize to the same data structure.

But the root problem here is just a spelling error; you have no-new-priviledges but you want no-new-privileges.

@larsks that will teach me to try and hand write it rather than copying my actual code. In the code I've spelt it correctly, it's was just my bad typing in the question.

What happens if you replace no-new-privileges=true  with no-new-privileges? Does that make the scanner happy? Docker seems to like both.

@larsks - it didn't seem to change anything. I suspect this is probably a problem with Checkmarx and not how it's set.

Perhaps the parser has the same issue as the highlighter here, and has converted it to a boolean. Try - 'no-new-privileges=true' or maybe even - new-privileges=false.

The warning disappears with:
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true

(Note the lack of spaces.)
This is the only combination I've found that Checkmarx recognises.

I'll give it a go and see if Checkmarx is happy.
